# Как сделать, чтобы String str = любому значению из массива?

Tags: java

нужно чтобы String str = любому значению из массива, чтобы можно было написать

```
public static void say() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();

    String str = in.nextLine();

    switch(str) {
        case("Привет"):
            System.out.println(HELLO[random.nextInt(HELLO.length)]);break;
        case("Привет!"):
            System.out.println(HELLO[random.nextInt(HELLO.length)]);break;
        case("привет"):
            System.out.println(HELLO[random.nextInt(HELLO.length)]);break;

    }
    say();
```

нужно чтобы по несколько раз не писать case и не писать повторно Sout.

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();....if(map.containsKey(str)) System.out.println(map.get(str));`

Comment: Не очень понятно что происходит. Может покажете настоящий код в котором несколько раз написано case и повторяется sout?

Comment: Как выглядит задача? Вы хотите проверить, ввел пользователь "привет" в любой комбинации строчных-заглавных букв или что-то другое?

Comment: Судя по вашему коду совершенно неважно, что вводит пользователь. Формула для вывода случайного значения одинакова.

Comment: пока что это неважно потому что ответы на hello одинаковы а вот если добавить пока то ответы будут другим и формула тоже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное Вам нужно что то подобное:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random random = new Random();
String str = in.nextLine();

Map<String, String[]> db = new HashMap<>();

String[] hellos = new String[]{"Привет", "Алоха"};
String[] helloAnswers = new String[]{"Здравствуй", "Добрых вечеров!"};
for (String hello : hellos) {
   db.put(hello, helloAnswers);
}

String[] goodbyes = new String[]{"Пока", "Прощай"};
String[] goodbyeAnswers = new String[]{"До свидания", "Ну пока"};
for (String goodbye: goodbyes) {
   db.put(goodbye, goodbyeAnswers);
}

if  (db.containsKey(str)) {
    String[] answers = db.get(str);
    System.out.println(answers[random.nextInt(answers.length)]);
}
```

PS: могут быть ошибки, писано с телефона...

Comment: @doodocina `switch` тут не подойдет, я подправил пример чтобы не было повторов `put`

Comment: можно ли сделать с if?

Comment: @doodocina https://i.imgur.com/GRhbQlj.png у вас java какая?

Comment: 1.8.0_211 jdk..

Comment: @doodocin у меня тоже 8 и как видите по скриншоту все собралось и отработало

Comment: его можно в void say или обязательно в psv main?

Comment: @doodocina это не важно